# Given start date and period: Find start date of current period

Tags: algorithm, date

Each customer has their individual contract start date (YYYY-MM-DD) and billing period (full calendar months).

Given any current day, I want to find the date the current billing period has started.

Some examples:

```
| Start date | Billing period | Current date | Start of current period |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------|
| 2018-01-01 | 12 Months      | 2020-09-25   | 2020-01-01              |
| 2018-01-01 | 6 Months       | 2020-09-25   | 2020-07-01              |
| 2018-01-01 | 18 Months      | 2020-09-25   | 2019-07-01              |
| 2018-01-01 | 13 Months      | 2020-09-25   | 2020-03-01              |
```

My naive approach would be to start adding periods to the start date until the resulting date is bigger than the current date. Then take the date before that iteration. However, I don’t like this, since with ongoing time the loop would take longer and longer.

Comment: What have **YOU** tried so far? Where did **YOU** get stuck? Share your code.

Comment: @MrSmith42 Added my first approach.

Comment: You naive approach is good, and can be optimized in a straightforward way. Consider the following question: "How many times can I put 7 in 25?" One way to do it is to start at 0, then add 7 until you go over 25. 7+7+7 = 21; 7+7+7+7 = 28; hence the answer is 3.This is your naive approach. But of course there is a much faster way. Can you see it?

Comment: @Rob so each line is for a customer ? Why there is a different start of billing period for each customer ?

Comment: Yep, each line is a customer. To make the examples easier, I chose the same start date for each customer. However, these vary depending on when the customer signed up for the product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic idea is to divide the passed months from contract start to now through the period length. The remainder represents the number of months we’re into the current period. So subtract that remainder from the current month and we should end up with the starting month of the period we’re in.

This is how I solved it for now (written in PHP):

```php
public function getStartDateOfCurrentPeriod(DateTime $contractStart, int $periodLength) : DateTime
{
    $now = new DateTime();

    $start = [
        'year' => intval($contractStart->format('Y')),
        'month' => intval($contractStart->format('m')),
        'day' => intval($contractStart->format('d'))
    ];

    $now = [
        'year' => intval($now->format('Y')),
        'month' => intval($now->format('m')),
        'day' => intval($now->format('d'))
    ];

    if ($start['day'] > $now['day']) {
        $now['month'] -= 1;

        if ($now['month'] <= 0) {
            $now['year'] -= 1;
            $now['month'] += 12;
        }
    }

    $start['months'] = $start['year'] * 12 + $start['month'];
    $now['months'] = $now['year'] * 12 + $now['month'];

    $monthsPassed = $now['months'] - $start['months'];

    $usedFromPeriod = $monthsPassed - floor($monthsPassed / $periodLength) * $periodLength;

    $yearDelta = floor($usedFromPeriod / 12);
    $monthDelta = $usedFromPeriod - $yearDelta * 12;

    $periodStart = [
        'year' => $now['year'] -  $yearDelta,
        'month' => $now['month'] - $monthDelta,
        'day' => $start['day']
    ];

    if ($periodStart['month'] <= 0) {
        $periodStart['year'] -= 1;
        $periodStart['month'] += 12;
    }

    return new DateTime(sprintf('%u-%u-%u', $periodStart['year'], $periodStart['month'], $periodStart['day']));
}
```